# Errors While Installing Bumblebee on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

Yesterday I installed Bumblebee-nvidia;but I am getting warnings as shown below:

[image: Warning Image]

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and I have nvidia 396.26 installed.

Comment: You should remove bumblebee ... it's not the recommend way to use NVIDIA drivers on Ubuntu. :)

Comment: @cl-netbox Removed!!